# Passing python list as argument to R function in rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2

I am starting with rpy2 with python for data analysis. I can pass simple python variable(like z=2.534) to R function in rpy2 as:

```
value=robjects.r('''
f<-function(z){
# process and return something
}
f('''+str(z)+''')
''')
```

But, when I pass list for z like z=[1,2,3] for above code str(z) does not work and when I manually pass '[1,2,3]' for str(z) ,function f would obviously be unable to work with character data as the list in R.

I need to find mean of items in list like [1,2,3] so how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on [evaluating R code](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/introduction.html#evaluating-r-code) suggests:

```
f = robjects.r('''
f<-function(z){
    # process and return something
}''')

value = f(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  There is a FloatVector and StrVector as well.

```
res = robjects.IntVector([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: The problem is what to write in place of 'str(z)'. If in its place `res` is passed error is raised as `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'IntVector' objects`

Comment: if z = [1,2,3]   res = robjects.IntVector(z).  Maybe I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You can print z with print(z) but it seems like str() does not operate on robjects.  I think that is your concern, right?

Comment: You can probably str the individual elements.  Or overload str() to process robjects.